# What is the PATH environment variable and how do I add to it?

Tags: software-installation, environment-variables

I just installed `picc-9.82.9453-linux.run` from Microchip website, and at the end it asked me

```
==> NOTE: You may wish to add the following  
   /usr/hitech/picc/9.82/bin  
   to your PATH environment variable.
```

What does it mean?

I also need to add this to the environment path:

```
/usr/hitech/picc-18/pro/9.66/bin
```

Comment: PATH is a global operating system variable that contains names of files that are to be executed without specyfing the whole path to them. For example You can just write `startx` to start graphic environemnt instead of `/bin/some other folders/startx`

Comment: After editing .profile restart your system to get the changes to take effect. (Perhaps there is a way around this, but restarting certainly works)

Comment: Run `. ~/.profile` for changes to take immediate effect

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Partial duplicate: [How to add a directory to the PATH?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path)

PATH is an enviroment variable. It basically tells your machine where to search for programs, so when you run your picc program you can just do this:

```
picc
```

instead of

```
/usr/hitech/picc/9.82/bin/picc
```

To add a directory to your `$PATH`, follow either one of the options below.

#### Method 1

Edit `~/.profile`:

```
gedit ~/.profile
```

find the following line:

```
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

and change it to:

```
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH:/usr/hitech/picc/9.82/bin"
```

#### Method 2

Run the command below in the terminal:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/hitech/picc/9.82/bin
```

Comment: i do not clearly understand what do  
i edited `/etc/profile`  
but the link in your answer says something like this  
`if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then  
  PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"  
fi  `
what do do with this?

Comment: There you go. I updated the answer.

Comment: what to do if i need to add more than 1 path?

Comment: Just keep adding a colon, then your new path to that string. i.e. `PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH:/usr/hitech/picc/9.82/bin:/my/new/path"`

Comment: What if there is no `~/.profile` file there?

Comment: Then try this: `code`gedit .profile

Comment: This will help others. I typed /home/myUserName/Installs/Spark/bin after Path:     to get to my main folder and then point it to the whatever I needed. $HOME did not work or HOME,

Answer (score 18):

Shell environment variables are used for several purposes, from storing data, storing software configurations, set terminal settings, and changing shell environment. The environment variables are normally set at boot time, or by different software as required. One way of setting environmental variables is from the command line.

### List all variables on terminal

```
env
```

this will print all the variable that you have

### Show one variable at a time

The amount of these variables can become a very long list and locating one specific variable can become a tough task. Fortunately Linux allows us to display the value of one shell variable by using the `echo` command along with the name of the variable. This makes the task very easy.
example: `echo "$HOME"`

### Add or change a variable

To add or modify an environment variable, we can use the export command followed by the name of the variable and the values that go with it.

```
export NameofVariable='value'
```

Note, however, that this will only work for the current shell session. It won't be available in any other terminals.

Comment: Hi there, great first answer! Oh, and welcome to Ask Ubuntu!

Answer (score 3):

```
vi(m) ~/.profile
PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:{whatever_path_you_need_to_add}:$PATH"
```

If you don't have .profile file... this will also create one:

In that scenario add this also-

```
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
   # include .bashrc if it exists
   if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
      . "$HOME/.bashrc"
   fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin directories

PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:/usr/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the environment variable in `~/.bashrc` and log out, then log in and everything is working fine.

Step by step:

1. `sudo nano ~/.bashrc`.
2. add this `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin` to the end of the file.
3. `source ~/.bashrc`, and everything works!

Note:
To ensure the `go` working properly, open terminal and type `go version` then you will see the *go help*.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Instead of steps 3 and 4, you can just use `source ~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Thanks, @MikaelF. I edited the answer.