# How do I enable ccache?

Tags: bash, bashrc

I am completely noob at this. I don't know what the make file is, and I don't know what `bashrc` is.

But I do know where to download source code and use source somebash.sh then make file (as was told by someone to run those commands).

I did some research and found out *ccache* can speed up sequential build speed, but I have no idea what am I supposed to do when reading those online instructions (include *ccache* in path, what path, where and how, and gcc, colorgcc, and bashrc. What are these?)

What is a step-by-step instruction?

Comment: If you don't know what you are doing, why are you concerned with increasing efficiency? Shouldn't you be more focused on figuring out the very basics? You should figure out what your end goal is, then figure out how to get there. Ask questions here about specific things you are trying to figure out that get you to that goal. If you don't know what a path is, then forget about `ccache`.

Comment: so what's a PATH (in Linux definition, I know what path is in windows environment)

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/141718/what-is-path-environment-variable-and-how-to-add-it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would read [this](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/ccache.1.html) documentation, and then

> 1. `sudo apt-get install ccache`
> 2. Assuming you're build a "standard" source package,

```
export CC="ccache gcc"
export CXX="ccache g++"
./configure
```

If you really want to "override" the standard `gcc` and `g++` you could then

```
ln -s $(which ccache) /usr/local/bin/gcc
ln -s $(which ccache) /usr/local/bin/g++
ln -s $(which ccache) /usr/local/bin/cc
```

Answer (score 5):

You can look into [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Ccache) documentation, for example. Briefly:

1. Install the **ccache** package -- you know, `sudo apt-get install ccache`
2. Put the following line into your `~/.bashrc`:

`export PATH="/usr/lib/ccache/bin/:$PATH"`

Of course, please check if `/usr/lib/ccache/bin` really exists, it might be installed elsewhere.

Comment: nope, ccache doesnot exisst in /usr/lib, if not, how can i find out where the program is installed?

Comment: Try `dpkg-query -L ccache`

Comment: @user97662 On Ubuntu 22.04 it seems to exist, although the binaries are now just in `/usr/lib/ccache/`, not in `/usr/lib/ccache/bin`.

Answer (score 1):

Make install from source. It's working for me.

Download:

```
wget https://www.samba.org/ftp/ccache/ccache-3.3.3.tar.gz
```

Uncompress:

```
tar -zxvf ccache-3.3.3.tar.gz
```

Enter folder:

```
cd ccache-3.3.3
```

To compile and install `ccache`, run these commands:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

Create a symbolic link for `ccache`:

```
cp ccache /usr/local/bin/
cd /usr/local/bin/
ln -s ccache /usr/local/bin/gcc
ln -s ccache /usr/local/bin/g++
ln -s ccache /usr/local/bin/cc
ln -s ccache /usr/local/bin/c++
```