# How do I set up ccache?

Tags: 12.04, compiling, makefile

I want to use [ccache](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/ccache.1.html) to speed up compilation.

I came across *[How do I enable ccache?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/466059/how-do-i-enable-ccache)*.

This is what I have done so far:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y ccache
$ dpkg -l ccache
ii  ccache  3.1.6-1   Compiler cache for fast recompilation of C/C++ code
$ whereis ccache
ccache: /usr/bin/ccache /usr/lib/ccache /usr/bin/X11/ccache /usr/share/man/man1/ccache.1.gz
```

I appended `ccache` to the path by adding it to my `~/.bashrc` file:

```
$ export PATH="/usr/lib/ccache:$PATH"
$ source ~/.bashrc
$ echo $PATH
/usr/lib/ccache:/usr/local/cuda-5.5/bin/:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

The symbolic links look fine:

```
$ ll /usr/lib/ccache/
total 76
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 mai   22 10:48 ./
drwxr-xr-x 253 root root 69632 mai   22 10:48 ../
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    16 mai   22 10:48 avr-g++ -> ../../bin/ccache*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    16 mai   22 10:48 avr-gcc -> ../../bin/ccache*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    16 mai   22 10:48 avr-gcc-4.5.3 -> ../../bin/ccache*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    16 mai   22 10:48 c++ -> ../../bin/ccache*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    16 mai   22 10:48 c89-gcc -> ../../bin/ccache*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    16 mai   22 10:48 c99-gcc -> ../../bin/ccache*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    16 mai   22 10:48 cc -> ../../bin/ccache*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    16 mai   22 10:48 g++ -> ../../bin/ccache*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    16 mai   22 10:48 g++-4.6 -> ../../bin/ccache*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    16 mai   22 10:48 gcc -> ../../bin/ccache*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    16 mai   22 10:48 gcc-4.6 -> ../../bin/ccache*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    16 mai   22 10:48 x86_64-linux-gnu-g++ -> ../../bin/ccache*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    16 mai   22 10:48 x86_64-linux-gnu-g++-4.6 -> ../../bin/ccache*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    16 mai   22 10:48 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -> ../../bin/ccache*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    16 mai   22 10:48 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-4.6 -> ../../bin/ccache*
```

The link looks good:

```
$ which g++
/usr/lib/ccache/g++

$ make
g++ -o affine_euler affine_euler.cpp -O3 -DEIGEN_NO_DEBUG -I/usr/include/eigen3
g++ -o test_eigen test_eigen.cpp -O3 -DEIGEN_NO_DEBUG -I/usr/include/eigen3
```

But the cache is empty:

```
$ ccache -s
cache directory                     /home/dell/.ccache
cache hit (direct)                     0
cache hit (preprocessed)               0
cache miss                             0
files in cache                         0
cache size                             0 Kbytes
max cache size                       1.0 Gbytes
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: I realized it works in the general case but not with my makefile (works with cmake for example). So I guess the problem is in my makefile and not in ccache configuration.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

### Installation:

```
# Install package
sudo apt install -y ccache

# Update symlinks
sudo /usr/sbin/update-ccache-symlinks

# Prepend ccache into the PATH
echo 'export PATH="/usr/lib/ccache:$PATH"' | tee -a ~/.bashrc

# Source bashrc to test the new PATH
source ~/.bashrc && echo $PATH
```

Your path (at least the beginning) should look like:

```
/usr/lib/ccache:/usr/local/cuda-5.5/bin/:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

And `g++`/`gcc` should now point to:

```
which g++ gcc
/usr/lib/ccache/g++
/usr/lib/ccache/gcc
```

### Configuration:

If you want no limit to the number of files and size of the cache:

```
ccache -F 0
ccache -M 0
```

Show cache statistics:

```
ccache -s
```

Empty the cache and reset the stats:

```
ccache -C -z
```

### Usage:

Every time you call `gcc` or `g++`; `ccache` is called. My mistake was that I didn't delete already-compiled files. Just delete all your `CMake`/output files and configure/compile again.

Your `ccache` shouldn't be empty then. Now try a `make clean` and `make` and you'll see it is much faster than re-compiling everything thanks to the cache.

Comment: some how after following this instruction, ccache does not cache clang and clang++ ...

Answer (score 4):

Your `$PATH` doesn't look correct; `ccache`'s directory should be in there. Just run:

```
export PATH="/usr/lib/ccache/:$PATH"
```

... and try your `g++` commands again. This directory is full of proxy commands that call `ccache`. This should work with most scripts.

---

If you're just calling `g++` manually (not like above where you're using make), you can just prepend the command:

```
ccache g++ ...
```

Comment: This directory doesn't exist:

`$ ls -1 /usr/lib/ccache/
avr-g++
avr-gcc
avr-gcc-4.5.3
c++
c89-gcc
c99-gcc
cc
g++
g++-4.6
gcc
gcc-4.6
x86_64-linux-gnu-g++
x86_64-linux-gnu-g++-4.6
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-4.6
`

Comment: I was reading an Arch tutorial. If everything's just in `/usr/lib/ccache/` just use that.

Comment: It doesn't work with `export PATH="/usr/lib/ccache/:$PATH"`

ccache binary is in `/usr/bin` and `/usr/bin/X11`. I tried with both these paths without success

Comment: But the proxy commands (as you've listed above) are all in `/usr/lib/ccache/`. You add these to your path so that when `make` calls `g++` or `cc` or whatever, it's actually calling the `ccache`-enabled version.

Comment: I'm close because the link now points to ccache (I edited the first post) but the cache is always empty.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding installation:

I've found that on [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) (Bionic Beaver) the shipped default does not catch invocations of `cc` and `c++`. To fully install ccache there, you need:

```
sudo apt install ccache
sudo /usr/sbin/update-ccache-symlinks
export PATH="/usr/lib/ccache/:$PATH"
```

And then (due to updated symlinks) also calls to `cc` and `c++` get caught!