# How to install ccache version 3.2 on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

Current latest version of [ccache](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ccache) is 3.1.9, but that one [doesn't have proper support for clang](https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=8118).

How should I go about installing ccache 3.2.x?

Note: I'd prefer using package management if possible, so I can later remove the package with it if needed.

I have a previous version, 3.1.9, in /usr/bin/ccache and its symlinks at /usr/lib/ccache. These paths need to continue to work.

Comment: I noticed there is no 'ccache' tag, and I don't have enough rep to create it. I think it would be useful, I could find similar questions like [this one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/470545/how-do-i-set-up-ccache) then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing it from the source seems to have following drawbacks:

- you cannot remove it later using a package manager (checkinstall can be used to circumvent this up to a point)
- without specifying a path to ./configure, it won't go to where the previous version was
- the most important one: links in /usr/lib/ccache will not get created

At least for me, the most working solution was to use updated package from a newer version of ubuntu, Wily. Doing like this:

1. Download the package from http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/amd64/ccache/download (assuming you're on amd64 architecture)
2. Installing it: `sudo dpkg -i ccache_3.2.3-1_amd64.deb`

Will have everything working like I wanted to:

```
$ ccache -V
ccache version 3.2.3

Copyright (C) 2002-2007 Andrew Tridgell
Copyright (C) 2009-2015 Joel Rosdahl

This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under
the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by the Free Software
Foundation; either version 3 of the License, or (at your option) any later
version.
$ ls -trla /usr/lib/ccache
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 86 root root 12288 Jan 27 17:55 ..
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    16 Jan 27 17:55 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-4.8 -> ../../bin/ccache
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    16 Jan 27 17:55 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -> ../../bin/ccache
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    16 Jan 27 17:55 x86_64-linux-gnu-g++-4.8 -> ../../bin/ccache
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    16 Jan 27 17:55 x86_64-linux-gnu-g++ -> ../../bin/ccache
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    16 Jan 27 17:55 gcc-4.8 -> ../../bin/ccache
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    16 Jan 27 17:55 gcc -> ../../bin/ccache
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    16 Jan 27 17:55 g++-4.8 -> ../../bin/ccache
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    16 Jan 27 17:55 g++ -> ../../bin/ccache
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    16 Jan 27 17:55 cc -> ../../bin/ccache
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    16 Jan 27 17:55 c99-gcc -> ../../bin/ccache
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    16 Jan 27 17:55 c89-gcc -> ../../bin/ccache
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    16 Jan 27 17:55 c++ -> ../../bin/ccache
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    16 Jan 27 17:55 arm-none-eabi-gcc-4.8.2 -> ../../bin/ccache
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    16 Jan 27 17:55 arm-none-eabi-gcc -> ../../bin/ccache
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    16 Jan 27 17:55 arm-none-eabi-g++ -> ../../bin/ccache
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Jan 27 17:55 .
$ which ccache
/usr/bin/ccache
$ apt-cache policy ccache
ccache:
  Installed: 3.2.3-1
  Candidate: 3.2.3-1
  Version table:
 *** 3.2.3-1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.1.9-1 0
        500 http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
$
```

Answer (score 1):

Download the latest version of `ccache` from [cache.samba.org](https://ccache.samba.org/) for better performance.

After downloading, follow the steps as mentioned below:

1. Extract the files using `tar` command:

   ```
   tar -xvf ccache-3.2.4.tar.bz2
   ```
2. Go inside `ccache-3.2.4` folder and run the following commands:

   ```
   ./configure
   ./make
   sudo make install
   ```
3. Open `~/.bashrc` file in your editor and insert the following lines at the end of it:

   ```
   export CCACHE_DIR=/home/user_name/.ccache
   export CCACHE_TEMPDIR=/home/user_name/.ccache
   ```

   Note : fill `user_name` with your User name.
4. Save your `.bashrc` and source it as follows:

   ```
   source ~/.bashrc
   ```
5. To check ccache is working or not type : `ccache -s` to see the statistics

Comment: apt-get can only find the old version. there doesn't seem to be 3.2 on ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: please check update comment :)

Comment: thank you for the update! Is there a way for me to make a .deb package or similar when installing? I would much prefer something that would show up in package management.

Comment: also, this seems to never establish the symlinks at `/usr/lib/ccache`