# What does $PATH mean?

Tags: command-line

I am trying to install something and among the steps there was this one:

"Place it on your `$PATH`"

What does this mean? What is that?

I have searched both this site and on Google but everyone just takes it for granted!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a directory to my path?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path)

Comment: @muru No I have read that question and it has nothing in common with mine. Also this question was not helpful at all.

Comment: @muru I think the question is not about how to add (or I might be misunderstanding what is meant by "Place it on your $PATH").

Comment: @JacobVlijm you are right it is not.

Comment: I see. Alright. Related; http://askubuntu.com/q/141718/158442

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Run in a terminal:

```
echo $PATH
```

or

```
printf "%s\n" "$PATH"
```

what you see is a list of directories, looking like:

```
/home/jacob/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

If you put an executable in either one of these directories, you do not need to set the path to the executable / script, but you can run it by its name as a command.

Executables in `$PATH` should not [have a language extension](https://lintian.debian.org/tags/script-with-language-extension.html) by convention (although they would work)

#### Editing your $PATH variable

You can (permanently) add a directory to `$PATH` by adding the following line to your `~/.profile` file (invisible by default, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> in the file manager to make it visible):

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/dir
```

#### More usefull information on environment variables

(such as `$PATH`) can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) (thanks for the suggestions @Letizia)

Comment: we can suggest how to change it in .bashrc PATH=$PATH:/path/you/want, or in .profile, what do you think?

Comment: and this is a useful [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) for beginners

Comment: @Letizia I would prefer the first one. Did you remove your answer? we were pretty much at the same time. we could have made a nicely spread combination :)

Comment: Yes, I already done, my answer is removed and I thought that is better contribute to your. What do you think about my comment?

Comment: @Letizia comment = perfect, I will edit. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you both. This is very helpful. Also Letizia your answer was really good too.

Comment: @JacobVlijm regarding the extension convention: That is a packaging guideline, not meant for a personal addition.

Comment: @muru sure, but why not keep it?

Comment: @JacobVlijm sends out a signal as if it is somehow "wrong", when there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @muru I don't agree, I think there is no actual difference if it's your own or not, I think you shouldn't use language extensions in $PATH. Ugly in commands as well, but as I said it still does work.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Sorry, in that case, I must downvote. There is a reason why that recommendation is good for packages, and that reason does not hold for personal programs or personally-installed programs.

Comment: @muru, well do what you think you have to do, I think the signal is correct.

Answer (score 12):

`$PATH` is a [environment variable](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) that is [file location-related](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#File-location_related_variables).

When one types a command to run, the system looks for it in the directories specified by `PATH` in the order specified.

You can view the directories specified by typing `echo $PATH` in the terminal.

Suppose there is a executable file `foobar01.sh` present at `/home/user/foo1/foo2/foobar01.sh` which you want to execute on a regular basis. typing the entire "path" would be time consuming. So we add the directory in to `$PATH` variable and we can execute `foobar.sh` directly without even specifying the path.

You can add it to `$PATH` by typing the following command:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/user/foo1/foo2
```

Answer (score 5):

I assume you are coming from a Windows background (apologies if it is not true). In layman's terms, a path (or the search path) is the list of directories that will be searched for anything that you type on the command line. If you type in a built-in command like ls, it will look for a specified list of directories. You can look up your path by typing echo $PATH. Here is one difference between Windows and *nix: By default, Windows always looks for the executable file in the current directory. For example, if you have a file called uptime.bat in c:\myscripts, and you cd c:\myscripts and type in uptime, it will run. However, in *nix, the path will be consulted and the executable found (if available).

If you keep your scripts in a directory called /home/teresa/scripts, to execute those scripts, you will have to specify the full path to that directory. Example: /hone/teresa/checkHost. A variation would be to cd /home/teresa and then type ./checkHost (note the ./ which means that you  are explicitly asking the file to run from the current directory.

To avoid this, you can just type

export PATH=$PATH:/home/teresa/scripts

which means that, in addition to the path that already exists now, also search in /hone/teresa/scripts. However, the problem with this is that once you logout, this setting would be gone. So, you should edit the hidden file ~/.bashrc, find the PATH line there, and append it accordingly. I am assuming you use bash. In the case of other shells, the syntax and file are different.

As a new user, it is very tempting to have . in the search path, which basically means that also search in the current directory. However, that is not considered a good practice for reasons discussed elsewhere.

HTH