# Installing leiningen, how to move script to ~/bin?

Tags: software-installation, scripts

I am trying to install leiningen to an Ubuntu virtual machine. But I am having a very difficult time because of my lack of Ubuntu/linux knowledge. I am specifically stuck on step two of the leiningen install steps: `Place it on your $PATH where your shell can find it (eg. ~/bin)`

So I have had success downloading the script and editing its executable settings. But I am not sure how to move it to ~/bin. It usually just ends up "disappearing".

How might I move the script to that directory?

Comment: The script more than likely now sits in a file named ~/bin. Where is it in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The directory ~/bin

`~/bin` is simply a folder named "bin" in your personal home directory. 
"~" stands for your home directory, so `~/bin` is actually: `/home/<yourname>/bin`.

You probably still have to create the folder. You can do that just like you make any other folder, and move the executable into that folder (make sure the file *is* executable).

#### $PATH

`~/bin` is included in [`$PATH`](https://askubuntu.com/a/551993/72216) by default, which means that you can run executables inside the folder by a command that is simply equal to the *name* of the executable; you don't need to include the path to the script to run it.

#### Note

After you created `~/bin` and added the script, you will probably have to log out and back in for it to work (or alternativeley, run `source ~/.profile`, as suggested by @muru, @Thomas W.)

Comment: Alternatively, `source ~/.bashrc` might refresh the environment vars and give access to `~/bin`.  If the applicatino is a GUI applictaion though then a logout/login will be needed

Comment: IIRC it is `.profile` which adds `~/bin` to the PATH, not `.bashrc`.

Comment: @muru Thanks, I will remove it until I am sure.

Comment: @muru, you were correct, `source ~/.profile` did the job on my "clean" laptop.

Comment: @muru ahhh, you're right, it is ~/.profile - although my `.profile` and `.bashrc` have that definition for `~/bin` in `PATH` reversed - i think it was before the `~/bin` change added to `~/.profile`.  My bad!