# How can I add my weather indicator to Startup Applications?

Tags: command-line, login, .desktop, autostart

In spite of having enabled my weather indicator on the list of the Startup Applications, it never starts on startup; I have to do it manually all the time.

The command I entered is:

```
my-weather-indicator
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi Hilario, posted. Please mention if all is clear (or not).

Comment: Sorry I didn't know about that.It's done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How to find out

I installed `my-weather-indicator` from its ppa: `ppa:atareao/atareao`to find out. Its `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications` includes the line:

```
Exec=/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/my-weather-indicator/bin/my-weather-indicator
```

which indicates the command you need to run is:

```
/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/my-weather-indicator/bin/my-weather-indicator
```

You can see the content of the file by running the command:

```
cat /usr/share/applications/extras-my-weather-indicator.desktop
```

or:

```
gedit /usr/share/applications/extras-my-weather-indicator.desktop
```

Sometimes launchers (`.desktop` files) have multiple lines, starting with

#### To add it to Startup Applications

Choose Dash > Startup Applications > Add, and add the command

```
/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/my-weather-indicator/bin/my-weather-indicator
```

#### More information

The command you tried does not include the path to the executable:

```
my-weather-indicator
```

This only works if the executable is in [$PATH](https://askubuntu.com/a/551993/72216). The application however is installed in:

```
/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/my-weather-indicator/bin
```

You can find out which directories are in `$PATH` by the command:

```
echo $PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple GUI based answer is,

- Right-click on the indicator and select `Preferences`
- In the Preferences window, click on `General options` and check the `Autostart` option.