# Installation: Copy script somewhere into $PATH

Tags: bash, software-installation, themes, fish

I wanted to install [polybar-themes](https://github.com/adi1090x/polybar-themes) and one of the dependencies was [networkmanager_dmenu](https://github.com/firecat53/networkmanager-dmenu) so, i want to install it. Im on Ubuntu 20.04 and only valid option there for me is: `Copy script somewhere into $PATH` I have no idea on how to implement this, can someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PATH` is an environmental variable that contains a list of directories where the system searches for an executable that matched a command. See here for [more information](https://askubuntu.com/questions/551990/what-does-path-mean). The contents can be seen in your terminal with the command

```
echo $PATH
```

In theory, you thus could have your install program look at the directories in there, and install it in one of the directories listed.

However, there are [conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) on the use of directories. `sbins` directories are intended for system binaries, `bin` directories for all other executables. You thus will select a `bin` directory:

- If you distribute your executable (your script) through the packaging system of your distribution, place it in `/usr/bin`. For Ubuntu, this means your software is packaged as a `.deb` installation file.
- If your script is a custom installation script, then place your executable in `/usr/local/bin`. That directory is not managed by the packaging system of the operating system.

Answer (score -1):

Polybar themes are made to work with tiling window managers like dwm, bspwm, xmonad, i3 etc. By default ubuntu 20.04 comes with gnome which is not a tiling window manager. Therefore polybar does not work with regular ubuntu desktop, unless you install specifically a tiling window manager.

Comment: This is not true. While many people are using polybar with a tiling window manager, it will work on any window manager running on an X server.

Comment: @Patrick Ziegler Why the downvote? I never said that polybar does not work on X server. I said if the user has the default installation of Ubuntu, polybar would not work as they expect.

Comment: I downvoted because you said that polybar doesn't work properly on non-tiling WMs. Whether the WM uses tiling for its windows has no influence on polybar.