# How to create a PATH environment variable for Android Studio?

Tags: android, environment-variables

I am a newbie and have no idea about linux or ubuntu. I have successfully installed Android studio but have problem in opening it. The developer site instructs to add PATH environment variable but I don't even know what it means.

I have extracted android studio to home and additional folders - Android and AndroidStudioProjects created by the system after installation of android studio.

Prefer layman language if possible and step-by-step instructions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question is related to some of the other posts on askubuntu.com
The following might be of help in answering your questions about the PATH environment variable in general as well as your specific Android studio setup.

General PATH related questions on Linux:

[What is $PATH](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141718/what-is-path-environment-variable-and-how-to-add-it?rq=1)

[Add a directory to your path](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path)

There are also some old Android SDK path questions that may help you on askubuntu. You can find them by searching askubuntu for "android sdk path"