# Add android-studio/bin/ to PATH environmental variable

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, android, environment-variables

Recently I installed Android Studio. Now I want to add android-studio/bin/ persistently to PATH environmental variable as `Session-wide environment variables` and not as `System-wide environment variables`. To do that I tried to edit `~/.profile` as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/141723/485213). So I have these at the end of `~/.profile`:

```
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH:/usr/local/Android/android-studio/bin"
fi
```

Then I re-login to initialize the variable. But when I run `studio.sh` in terminal, I get this:

> studio.sh: command not found

Here are results of `$PATH` and `echo $PATH`:

```
$ $PATH 
bash: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:
No such file or directory 
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Also I'm sure that `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bash_login` do not exist. Now what cause the problem and how I can solve that?

Edit:

I change end of `~/.profile` to this, but it does not work:

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
    PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/Android/android-studio/bin"
fi
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you edited this code snippet:

```
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

which is included in `~/.profile` by default.

The answer which lead you to do so is confusing IMNSHO.

I'd suggest that you change that code back to what it looked like before, and instead add a new line underneath it:

```
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/Android/android-studio/bin"
```

Then, next time you log in, PATH ought to be altered, whether `$HOME/bin` exists or not.

Comment: I tried that, but it does not work. I edited question, please see it again.

Comment: @hasanghaforian: Ok, I edited my answer too to clarify.

Comment: Thank you for your attention and help!  But if I would to add another path, I have to add another line?

Comment: @hasanghaforian: Not necessarily. The point is that it shouldn't be between `if` and `fi`. As long as you keep it where it is now, you can say `PATH="$PATH:/some/directory:/some/other/directory"`

Comment: Once the path what is the command to execute the program globally?

Comment: @NickPineda: `studio.sh`, I suppose. (I don't use the program myself.)

Answer (score -1):

OK, there's a couple issues here:

1. Use `echo $PATH` instead of `$PATH` to check it!

   The reason for this is that bash replaces `$PATH` with the contents of that variable everywhere, so just running `$PATH` tries to execute the contents of the variable, which is nonsense to hte bash interpreter.
2. You should add the content you added to `~/.profile` to `~/.bashrc` as well.
3. Make sure that `"$HOME/bin"` exists by running `ls -d $HOME/bin`.  If you get an error like `bash: ls: No such file or directory.` then it doesn't exist.  If it does exist then you should get an output something like `/home/[username]/bin`.

If all those are satisfied then you should be good to go.  If you're not, then just use this command: `cd [path_to_studio_directory]; ./studio.sh` instead.  That way you will start inside that folder and guarantee its execution.

Comment: Why I have to add that to `~/.bashrc` when I did not that  here:https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables. Also how I can check the existence of `$HOME/bin`?

Comment: @hasanghaforian: That recommendation makes no sense to me either.

Comment: Because `~/.bashrc` always gets run when you enter Terminal.  It's just another check to ensure that it happens.  See edit for checking existence @hasanghaforian

Comment: If you use `~/.profile` to edit PATH, which is an environmental variable, the new value is available in the whole session, whether you use the terminal or not. If you do it right, you don't need "another check". ;)

Comment: Well, I've run into cases where `~/.profile` doesn't get processed at all, so I don't trust it as much...