# How can I update npm?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, nodejs, npm

I'm trying to install Yeoman so I can install AngularJS, but I run into problems regarding the version of npm. Here's the output when I run `npm install -g yo`:

```
npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.1.2: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm
/home/marieficid/.node/bin/yo -> /home/marieficid/.node/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/cli.js

> yo@1.6.0 postinstall /home/marieficid/.node/lib/node_modules/yo
> yodoctor


Yeoman Doctor
Running sanity checks on your system

✔ Global configuration file is valid
✖ Node.js version

Your Node.js version is outdated.
Upgrade to the latest version: https://nodejs.org

✔ No .bowerrc file in home directory
✔ No .yo-rc.json file in home directory
✖ npm version

Your npm version is outdated.

Upgrade to the latest version by running:
npm install -g npm

✔ NODE_PATH matches the npm root

Found potential issues on your machine :(
/home/marieficid/.node/lib
└── yo@1.6.0
```

And here's the output when I run `npm install -g npm@latest` (my current version is 3.7.3):

```
/home/marieficid/.node/bin/npm -> /home/marieficid/.node/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
/home/marieficid/.node/lib
└── npm@3.7.3
```

Anyone knows how to fix this?

**EDIT:** running `sudo npm --version` returns 2.14.12 instead of 3.7.3.

Comment: What is the result of `which npm`? What about `sudo which npm`? It sounds like you might have multiple versions of node/npm installed.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have a `.npmrc` file in your home folder that contains a `prefix` variable.

If this is the case you will have to update your $PATH variable adding the new bin path, in your case `$HOME/.node/bin/`, also ensure it is after which ever path npm is currently in, this you can find out by using `which npm`. To set your path variable: [What is the PATH environment variable and how do I add to it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141718/what-is-path-environment-variable-and-how-to-add-it) and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

Comment: Hey @JKamzi, I appreciate the help a lot, however I seem to have done something very wrong and when I try to run `npm install -g n` I get `/usr/bin/env: node: File or directory not found`, do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: You have most likely messed up your `$PATH` variable.  Can you run `echo $PATH` in your terminal and ensure everything is fine. it should look something like this export PATH=$PATH:/some/other/path:/another/path

Comment: It's definitely messed up. Here's what I get: `/home/marieficid/.node/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin` Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Your path looks fine. However on *buntu system it seem node is installed as `nodejs`. Symlnk seem to work `ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node`

Comment: I hope you don't mind me asking for help again - I tried running this line `ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node` and I got an error: `ln: failed to create link “/usr/bin/node”: File exists` I tried the other way around and got the same error. Do you know what to do?

Comment: I managed to get it working, thanks a lot for your help!