# Python 3 default interpreter

Tags: python3, anaconda

I've installed Anaconda (with Python 3.5.2) and although while using IPython/PyCharm (after setting it to use Anaconda) I have access to all the packages, while using Python 3 through the terminal it refers to the python3.5.1 that comes with Ubuntu and it doesn't recognize any package.

I've set my path as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/828882/installing-anaconda?noredirect=1&lq=1)

`echo $PATH`:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/myname/anaconda3/bin
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Can you do `echo $PATH` and add its output to your question?

Comment: @edwinksl done that

Comment: Where and how did you set your `PATH`?

Comment: @edwinksl see the link

Comment: Put the path for Anaconda in front of everything else, i.e., do `export PATH=/home/ofirarzi/anaconda3/bin:$PATH`. Then do `source ~/.profile` and see if it works.

Comment: Sounds good, let me write up something with slightly more details.

Comment: you said you're going to write one yourself, didnt want to steal it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you were setting your `PATH` using

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/ofirarzi/anaconda3/bin
```

Unfortunately, this means that `/usr/bin/python3` comes first before `//home/ofirarzi/anaconda3/bin/python3`, so your system Python 3 gets called instead of Anaconda's Python 3 when you run `python3` in the terminal. To fix this, you just need to reverse the order of the components of `PATH`, i.e., in your `~/.profile`, do

```
export PATH=/home/ofirarzi/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

Then do `source ~/.profile` and try `python3` again. For the new `PATH` to take effect in the terminal in the future without manually sourcing `~/.profile` every time, you have to log out and then log in again or reboot.

Note that the way I have exported `PATH` is also described by Anaconda's documentation at https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install#linux-install.